# how could i get width of div which has flex grow property from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to get the width of a div element , consider class name abc,
flex grow property is applied to this div. 
i wanted to get the width of this div after growth of div and apply the same width to someother div with class name as abc2.
thanks in advance !

```js
//i tried this thing
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
var width=y[0].offsetWidth;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('abc2');
x[0].style.width = width+'px';

// im not getting the same width as .abc for .abc2
```

```css
.parent1, .parent2{
 display: flex;
 }
 .abc{
  flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vh;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffd3b6;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    }
.abc2{
    background-color: #ffd3b6;
    height: 10vh;
    padding: 10px;
    
    text-align: center;
    }
 .other{
    background-color: #ffd3b6;
    height: 10vh;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    width:50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="abc">i want this expanded width</div>
  <div class="abc">i want this expanded width</div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="abc2">i want to get same width as div of abc</div>
  <div class="other">  random</div>
  <div class="other">  random</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: HI. Please share the code via codepen or JSFiddle.

Comment: just added to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you set the padding of `abc2` to be `padding: 10px 0px;` then the width will be correct.

Basically your calculation is not taking into account the padding.

```js
//i tried this thing
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
var width=y[0].offsetWidth;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('abc2');
x[0].style.width = width+'px';

// im not getting the same width as .abc for .abc2
```

```css
.parent1, .parent2{
 display: flex;
 }
 .abc{
  flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vh;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffd3b6;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    }
.abc2{
    background-color: #ffd3b6;
    height: 10vh;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    
    text-align: center;
    }
 .other{
    background-color: #ffd3b6;
    height: 10vh;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    width:50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="abc">i want this expanded width</div>
  <div class="abc">i want this expanded width</div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="abc2">i want to get same width as div of abc</div>
  <div class="other">  random</div>
  <div class="other">  random</div>
</div>
```